# See if values of my dataframe is one of the values in an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extend

I have two questions.

I would like to select rows from a dataframe called `df_12` when the value of `STABBR` column is one of the elements of an array called `states100`.
The array is the states that had 100+ respondents to a survey.

```
states100 = ['CA','TX','NY','FL','PA','OH','IL','MI','MO',
             'NC','MA','GA','TN','VA','NJ','IN','MN','PR',
             'OK','AZ','CO','WA','WI','LA','KY','SC','CT',
             'KS'
            ]
```

And dataframe is like this:

[image: first few rows of dataframe called df_12]

What I would like select the row when the value of `STABBR` is one of the elements of `states100` array. I tried to use `for` loop, but I am not sure how `for` loop work in dataframe situation.

Next question is, with those selected rows I would like to fill in an empty pandas dataframe. When I did `pd.dataframe(index=df_12.index, columns=df_12.columns)` to create an empty dataframe, it already has already set shape (which is the shape of df_12), and when the number of selected rows are less than the empty dataframe's shape, there will be plenty of NaN in the dataframe. I would like to extend the empty dataframe whenever a new row is added.

Comment: `df_12[df_12['STABBR'].isin(states100)]`

Comment: Thank you @CodeDifferent